# Navigation back to MainPage after setting language

Tags: maui

I have a Settings ContentPage in a .NET MAUI App in which a user can set the preferred language via Picker.

The SelectedItem is bound to a Property and in there the Language Setting is stored via `Preferences.Default.Set(Constants.ApplicationLanguage, selectedLanguage);`

As the Settins ContentPage is reached via Flyout-Item and set via Picker, I thought it might be good to navigate back to the MainPage directly after selecting the Language in the Picker and storing the preferences.

Therefore, I have the following code in the ViewModel:

```cs
public KeyValuePair<string, string> SelectedLanguage
{
    get => _selectedLanguage;
    set
    {
        _selectedLanguage = value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Key))
        {
            LocalizationResourceManager.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(value.Key);
            LanguageResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(new CultureInfo(value.Key));

            SetLanguagePreferences(value.Key);

            Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this means when I first call the Settings-Page it sets the language here and navigates back to the MainPage. So, I currently have to call the Settings-Page twice. Additionally, when I select the same language it stayed on the Settings Page and did not navigate back to the MainPage.

How could I solve these issues and in general make this better?

Comment: I don’t understand why you have to navigate to settings twice?

Comment: I see the problem. You shouldn't perform any navigation directly inside of a property setter. Navigation should be explicit, so right after the selection by the user happens. Setting the `SelectedLanguage` can occur for different reasons, not all of them involve user interaction while you only want to navigate upon user interaction. Please show how you use the picker and the result of the selection to set `SelectedLanguage`.

Comment: @Jason - Twice because in the SelectedLanguage Property the navigation is done and when the Settings page is loaded the first time it runs through the SelectedLanguage property setter

Comment: @Julian - Here is the XAML for the Picker:  ```<Picker Margin="5, 20, 5, 20"  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"  ItemsSource="{Binding PickerItemList}"                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage}" />```. So as soon as the picker is closed the SelectedLanguage property setter, which is bound, is called and the navigation is done.

Comment: as @Julian mentions, doing this in the setter isn't a great idea.  I'd suggest using a `Done` button to trigger the save and back navigation.  Or you can add some simple logic too the setter to not execute the navigation until the page load is complete.

Comment: @OXO Please **do not add code to comments**, you can edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend performing any navigation directly inside of a property setter. Navigation should be explicit and based on some user interaction. Setting the `SelectedLanguage` can occur for different reasons, not all of them involve user interaction while you only want to navigate upon user interaction.

The constructor of your ViewModel probably sets the property and thus executes the navigation statement before any user interaction took place, which is obviously not what you want. Presumably, this only happens the first time you open the Page, because the ViewModel is probably registered as a *singleton* and not as a *transient*. However, to be sure of this, we'll need to see more of the ViewModel as well as your XAML (and possibly the code-behind).

A very crude solution would be to perform the navigation in an event handler for the `Unfocused` event of the Picker control, which is only executed once the Picker is closed (losing focus):

XAML:

```xml
<Picker
    Margin="5, 20, 5, 20"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding PickerItemList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage}"
    Unfocused="OnLanguagePickerUnfocused" />
```

Code-behind:

```cs
private async void OnLanguagePickerUnfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs args)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage");
}
```

Don't forget to remove the navigation statement from your property setter:

```cs
public KeyValuePair<string, string> SelectedLanguage
{
    get => _selectedLanguage;
    set
    {
        _selectedLanguage = value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Key))
        {
            LocalizationResourceManager.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(value.Key);
            LanguageResourceManager.Instance.SetCulture(new CultureInfo(value.Key));

            SetLanguagePreferences(value.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:** This approach will also execute the navigation code when the Picker loses focus for other reasons than selecting a value form the list, e.g. tapping outside of it or hitting the "cancel" button.*

Comment: I agree with what you said about the user interaction. Here it is just a very simple settings page that only allows to select a different language. As the Picker uses an explicit select action, I thought it would be enough to accept this as the selected language and I can leave this page, close the Flyout and be directly on the page I wanted. Maybe as I also work with Tabs, I actually needed to go back to the page I came from. But, this is a different subject then. BUT: here it is the question, would you add an OK-Button to confirm this Dialog and then leave the Settings page?

Comment: As a user I wouldn't expect to directly be navigating back to the MainPage after making a selection in the Picker, but that's just how I see it.

Comment: Okay, I can overthink this. My first item in the Flyout is a Main Page item. The intention here was, that I did not want to leave the Navigation from the Settings Page and click this Main Page item to get back. And to have it as quick as possible, I thought, I could do it like I did described in my question. But, I will think about that as you said you as a user would not expect that. Is there a way, I can navigate to the page, I originally came from? Must not be the MainPage, but a different page reached from one of my Bottom Tabs, but should not be a clicked Flyout-Item-Page